# Questions about symmetric spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I'm a little confused with the following questions:

(1) Why does a symmetric space $M=G/K$ of compact type have $\mathcal{R}^M\geq 0$?

(2) Moreover, why does $\chi(M)\neq 0$ if and only if ${\rm rk}\ G={\rm rk}\ K$?

(3) For a symmetric space $M=G/K$ of compact type with dimension $4k+1$, why does Kervaire semi-characteristic $\sigma(M)\neq 0$ iff ${\rm rk}\ G={\rm rk}\ K+1$?
Where $$\sigma(M):=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2k}b_{2i} \mod 2,\quad  b_{j}:=\dim H^j(M;\mathbb{R})$$

I don't know if the question is too easy on MO. Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance. By the way, are there some nice references for these questions to refer to?

Comment: ad(1) iirc: compactness implies that G embeds into SO(n), so the Killing form is negative semidefinite, thus the metric is a negative multiple of the Killing form, from where you can derive the sign of sectional curvature.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the second question?@ThiKu

Comment: This is the Hopf-Samelson Theorem proved in https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01378063.pdf . The proof uses that the Euler characteristic can be computed by counting fixed points of a suitable isometry (namely one that generates a maximal torus). There is no curvature involved in the proof.